# Group data in mysql

Tags: mysql

Isn't it possible to store table in table?
let's say I have a list of users and every user can be admin in one or more servers.
If user an admin, then I need to store "Expired", "Type" columns for every server.
So how better to store this information?
I don't want to make columns like this:

Server1_Expired   Server1_Type   Server2_Expired   Server2_Type etc.

Also I can create tables for every server and store the same content, but it looks ridiculous.

I'm sorry if it's hard to understand, I just don't know how to explain else.
Please try understand me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a table called `admin_servers` and have a few columns... `id, admin_id, server_id, type, expired`

This table creates a link between an admin and a server.  For each row, you also have a `type` and `expired` value.

Comment: so if user an admin in more than one server, he will have few rows, am I right?

Comment: Yep, that's right.  It's called a `one-to-many` relationship.  You have 1 user to many servers.